# I wrote a polynomial time integer factorization algorithm; I was wondering where it stands?

Tags: algorithm, prime-factoring

Below is the Python code for my algorithm that computes the unique prime factors of an integer `n` in `O(n*log(log(n)))` time. I was wondering where it ranks among other integer factorization algorithms; from what I've read the current state-of-the-art algorithm `GNFS` is subexponential which is slower than polynomial time.

```
def compute_prime_factors(n):
    slots = [[],[],[2]]
    current_slot = 2
    for j in range(n):
        slots.append([])
    while current_slot <= n:
        current_slot_prime_factors = slots[current_slot]
        if current_slot_prime_factors == []:
            if current_slot+current_slot <= n:
                slots[current_slot+current_slot].append(current_slot)
        else:
            for prime_factor in current_slot_prime_factors:
                if current_slot+prime_factor <= n:
                    slots[current_slot+prime_factor].append(prime_factor)
        current_slot += 1
    return slots[n]

def compute_exponents(n, prime_factors):
    exponents = []
    for prime_factor in prime_factors:
        exponent = 0
        while n % prime_factor == 0:
            n = n // prime_factor
            exponent += 1
        exponents.append(exponent)
    return exponents

N = 5589222
prime_factors = compute_prime_factors(N)
exponents = compute_exponents(N, prime_factors)
print(N, prime_factors, exponents)
```

So to conclude, my algorithm has an `O(n*log(log(n)))` time-complexity and a `O(n)` space-complexity and it computes the prime factors of an integer `n`. I was wondering if this is faster than the current best integer factorization algorithms.

Comment: GNFS is subexponential in the *size* of the integer (for some definitions of subexponential, not all of them)

Comment: The "size" of an integer factorization problem is not the *value* of `n`, but its size, i.e. number of bits, i.e. `log(n)`.  So what you have here is an algorithm to factor a `k`-bit number in `O(2^k log(k))` steps which is actually exponential time.

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm you present is unique and correct, but not very efficient. Let's look at the simplest possible method, trail division.

```cpp
std::vector<uint64_t> factors;
for (auto i = 2; i < n; ++i)
    while (n % i == 0) {
        factors.push_back(i);
        n /= i;
    }
}
if (n > 1)
    factors.push_back(n);
```

This algorithm has `O(n)` time complexity and `O(1)` space complexity which is superior to the posted method.

Modern factorization algorithms such as the [General Number Field Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) have `O(log n * log log n)` time complexity. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) provides a good overview.

I would suggest trying to implement some of the simpler methods such as [Wheel Factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization) or [Pollard's Rho Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) to get a feel for some of the techniques.

Comment: The code above does not produce any composite factors. Suppose that `n` is divisible by a composite factor `c`. The loop will divide `n` by all the factors of `c` before it tries `c`.

Comment: So the prime factors of an integer ```n``` can be calculated in ```O(n)``` time?

Comment: Yes, the simplest possible algorithm is `O(n)` time. The efficient algorithms are much better -- see the references in my answer.

Comment: My algorithm can actually calculate the prime factors for all integers from ```2``` to ```n```, do you think this algorithm is important enough to share with academia?

Comment: @wonggr btw if you want to factor all integers between `2` and `n` and store the results, there is a much nicer format to store the factorizations: for each integer, only store the lowest prime factor. Then you just have a single array instead of an array of arrays, and you can still factor every number trivially (get the lowest factor, divide by it, get the lowest factor of the result, etc, until you reach 1)